# Why does my ::before element only display if I use position absolute?

Tags: html, css, visibility, pseudo-element

I have a simple question that I can't seem to find the answer to, and it may be that I'm just not entering the correct search terms into Google, but after scratching my head while trying to gain a better understanding of this, I still turn up empty handed.

I have a `span` element, that has a `::before` pseudo-element, nothing special, just a simple circle. However, I noticed that I have to absolutely position the pseudo-element in order for it to be visible. I found this rather odd and am not sure if I just don't fully understand pseudo-elements of this nature, or if I'm incorrectly implementing the idea.

Either way, here is an example with and without the absolute positioning.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.no-absolute::before,
.absolute::before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f33;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.absolute {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<span class="no-absolute">No Absolute</span>
<span class="absolute">Absolute</span>
```

Why does my `::before` pseudo-element have to be absolutely positioned in order to be visible?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz the `::before` pseudo-class already has `content: '';`.

Comment: because you cannot set height to inline element and position absolute force the display to block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have absolute positioning. You just need to set display property for the ::before pseudo-element

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.no-absolute::before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f33;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="no-absolute">No Absolute</span
```

Comment: That was fast! Can you give an explanation for future readers as to why this is the case? I'd assume it's because the DOM doesn't know how to display the element without explicitly being told, but that's just an educated guess. Thanks for pointing that out! Also, can't accept for 6 more minutes. +1

Comment: pseudo-elements are given the 'initial' display property by default, which means 'inline'. In your case, you need to change the display property to 'inline-block' or 'block' in order to be able to make changes on a block level

Answer (score 2):

Your `pseudo` element needs a display property. I've added `display: block`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.no-absolute::before,
.absolute::before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f33;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.absolute {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<span class="no-absolute">No Absolute</span>
<span class="absolute">Absolute</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: you need `display` to give the pseudo-element size / shape (either `block` or `inline-block`).  `inline` elements do *not* accept width / height.

ALTERNATIVELY you could do it with `padding` to give it size / shape, but `display` with `width / height` makes the most sense.

```css
span {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.no-absolute::before,
.absolute::before {
display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f33;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="absolute">Absolute</span>
```